# change filename obtained from request_uri

Tags: bash, file, docker, nginx, lua

Can someone help me with the code below:

```
location / {
    content_by_lua_block {
       ngx.req.read_body()
       local filename = string.gsub(ngx.var.request_uri, "/", "")
       ngx.say(filename)
       local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
       local file = io.open("/tmp/filename", "w")
       file:write(data)
       file:close()
       ngx.say("body data:")
       ngx.print(data)
    } 
}
```

Basically I want the filename obtained from `request_uri` to be passed to `local file = io.open(/tmp/filename)`.

If I leave a static name `local file = io.open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")` then it works. How do I pass the variable filename as the new filename ?

I tried several things but cant get my head around it. I want the filename to be the new filename and saved in the location `/tmp/filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either compose a string using the concatenation operator `..`

```
local filename = string.gsub(ngx.var.request_uri, "/", "")

filename = "/tmp/" .. filename
```

or

```
filename = string.format("/tmp/%s", filename)
```

Comment: You are awesome! @Piglet